# Windows 10: How to change a theme slideshow time interval?

Tags: windows-10, themes, appearance

It's all int the title; I find myself unable to set a precise time interval defining how often the background pictures of the theme I am currently using change.

The only similar option available in Windows 10 settings applies only to single background images and not to multiple background images included in a theme.

Thanks in advance,

N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then put this in the run line and hit enter:

```
control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

It will launch the old control panel, which has support for setting different wallpapers on dual-head configurations.

Comment: Seems like you have an answer but i see it needs more explanation specially for new comers

Comment: Ty to everybody; yes I got the answer from the Microsoft Support Forums which is indeed just like aksnoball said.

Comment: The command no longer works in Windows 10 Creators Update. Use this command instead: 
`shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper`

Comment: @Ignatius you should add that as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set intervals of your choice, you can do it by modifying the registry. Please follow the below steps to set the slideshow intervals:

1. Open Run and type regedit.exe
2. Navigate to:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow

In here, the two important values are the Interval, and Shuffle.

Double click on Shuffle, and change the value to 1. OK.

Then change the Interval by double clicking on it. You'll first want to change the Base to Decimal, rather than Hexadecimal (otherwise you'll get unexpected interval values). Then change the value to your desired time, in milliseconds (10000ms for 10 seconds).

You can exit regedit now. The final step is to restart Explorer. You can do this through Task Manager if you know how, otherwise simply restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's Pretty Simple.

1. Just create a new folder with all your pictures in it.
2. Then head on to Personalisation via right-clicking on your desktop. 
   ( http://prntscr.com/8cq8xr )
3. Change the Background to "Slideshow" ( http://prntscr.com/8cq934 )
4. Browse to the desired folder
5. Set the time interval.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Hey, thank you and sorry if that was not clear but I am trying to set a time interval on background images contained in a ".deskthemepack" file. The pictures are but one type of items in the file, together with sound files and color files. How could I perform your step (1) on such a file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I found a way to do it:

1. Right-click and move to personalize
2. Click on Themes and choose your preferred theme to use
3. Now set background to slide show
4. You will see a drop down menu; 'Change picture every'
5. Select your preferred time