# On Windows 10 is it possible to do random wallpaper shuffler at an interval of less than 1 minute?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

I have checked various sites claiming to have instructions on how to set Windows 10 random wallpaper shuffle to a customized time but the instructions never seem to work, and are often a few years old.

My goal is that I want my wallpaper to change randomly every 30 seconds – this was possible under Windows 7.

Additionally, I would like it to be shuffled in a genuinely random fashion – I’ve noticed that under Windows 10 it often seems not to be genuinely shuffled and tends to cluster similar images together (I have over 45,000 wallpapers and it seems beyond coincidence that I regularly hits runs of themed images).

I fear the above may come across as very nit-picky but there are legit reasons I need it to be genuinely random and faster than 1 min – it’s a work related thing.

Actually, I’m currently trying to find an app that will allow me to do random customized interval slide shows so if anybody knows of any I’d be glad to hear.

Comment: welcome to superuser: This superuser question may help:- https://superuser.com/questions/968533/windows-10-how-to-change-a-theme-slideshow-time-interval             or this one :- https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-slideshow-every-10-seconds-windows-10  I could not get them to work fully but i have Stardock running my display

Comment: Type `regedit` in Start - Run (Winkey+R) and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow. The value named Interval is the time between pictures in milliseconds. Change your wallpaper after changing this to have it take effect. Plus this is a command line wallpaper changer - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/changewallpaper.html.

Answer (score 0):

Press Win + R to launch the Run window

Type:

shell:::{ED834ED6-4B5A-4bfe-8F11-A626DCB6A921} -Microsoft.Personalization\pageWallpaper

Hit Enter and you will open old style wallpaper setting interface.

Have a try.